# Compound literal is created once for a given scope

Tags: c, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, compound-literals

I'm pretty confused about `N2346::6.5.2.5/15` and `N2346::6.5.2.5/16` which states (emp. mine)

> 15 EXAMPLE 8 Each compound literal creates only a single object in a
> given scope
>
> ```
> struct s { int i; };
> int f (void)
> {
>     struct s *p = 0, *q;
>     int j = 0;
>     again:
>         q = p, p = &((struct s){ j++ });
>         if (j < 2) goto again;
>     return p == q && q->i == 1;
> }
> ```
>
> The function f() always returns the value 1.
>
> 16  Note that if an iteration statement were used instead of an
> explicit goto and a labeled statement, the lifetime of the unnamed
> object would be the body of the loop only, **and on entry next time**
> **around p would have an indeterminate value, which would result in**
> **undefined behavior**.

The quote appeared to me as a contradiction to another part of the Standard. Precisely:

`N2346::6.5.2.5/5`

> If the compound literal occurs outside the body of a function, the
> object has static storage duration; otherwise, it has automatic
> storage duration associated with the enclosing block.

meaning that block-scoped object created with compound literals have automatic storage duration.

`N2346::6.8/3` (emp. mine):

> The initializers of objects that have automatic storage duration, and
> the variable length array declarators of ordinary identifiers with
> block scope, **are evaluated and the values are stored in the object**s
> (including storing an indeterminate value in objects without an
> initializer) **each time the declaration is reached in the order of**
> **execution**, as if it were a statement, and within each declaration in
> the order that declarators appear.

So even if the `goto` statement in the example of `N2346::6.5.2.5/15` is replaced with an iteration statement the object created by compound literal should be re-created each time it's reached.

**QUESTION**: Why does replacing `goto` with an iteration statement yields UB? What's wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: Simply - pointer is referencing the object which does not exist anymore. It is the same as returning a pointer to automatic object when exiting the function

Comment: I wonder if the authors of the Standard considered corner cases involving `goto` when they wrote the lifetime rules for compound literals?  The stated rationale for not having their lifetime extend through the function was that doing so would suggest that each iteration of a loop would create a new object, but limiting the lifetime to block scope does nothing to avoid that corner case.  As it is, limiting the lifetime to block scope needlessly impairs the usefulness of compound literals, and the specification that only one object is created would forbid loop-unrolling optimizations from...

Comment: ...having different objects for each iteration of the loop, which could sometimes be very useful with const-qualified literals (e.g. if an inner loop iterates `i` from 0 to 4, and uses a compound literal `(const S){1,2,3,i};` a compiler might usefully generate five static-duration objects, one for each value of `i`, and have each unrolled iteration of the inner loop pass the address of one such object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> even if the goto statement in the example of N2346::6.5.2.5/15 is
> replaced with an iteration statement the object created by compound
> literal should be re-created each time it's reached.

You are correct - but the important point is that the end of the block signals the end of the object's storage duration. The undefined behavior is triggered on `q = p` in the second iteration, when `p` is no longer valid, and also on the `return` line outside of the iteration statement.

---

More concretely, the standard is alluding to code like this:

```
struct s { int i; };
int f (void)
{
    struct s *p = 0, *q;
    int j = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        q = p; // p is invalid in the second iteration
        p = &((struct s){ j++ });
    } // end of block - p is no longer valid!

    // p points to an object whose storage duration has expired, and so this is undefined behavior
    return p == q && q->i == 1;
}
```

you can see the final `return` statement referencing an object whose storage duration expired at the end of the `for` block, and the `q` variable being assigned to a pointer that's undefined in the second iteration.

The defining difference between the usage of `goto` and an iteration statement like a `for` loop is that objects created inside the `for` loop are only valid **inside the scope of the loop**.

Comment: Thanks, did not catch what the Standard meant.